# Flutter can't install firebase onto macOS

Tags: firebase, flutter, macos, dart, installation

I tried to install the firebase package for flutter. After running

```
flutter pub add firebase_core
```

It states "successfully installed". When  I then try to import it to my main.dart file using the following code, it throws an error.

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
```

> Target of URI doesn't exist:
> 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart'. Try creating the file
> referenced by the URI, or Try using a URI for a file that does exist.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Run `flutter pub get` and  try restarting your IDE, it should work.

Comment: After restarting VS Code it worked :)